# How can I get screenshots of my Commander's or Holo-Me's face in each of the eight fundamental mouth positions for animating stop motion dialog?

Tags: pc, elite-dangerous

Elite Dangerous: Odyssey added, among other things, the ability to walk around and emote. However, I've not yet found a way to control my character's face or otherwise cause my character to speak without otherwise moving while I'm pointing the in-game free camera suite at my own face.

I want to record a video tutorial and have parts of it be "narrated by" my in-game character, and my plan for this is to get a screenshot of my character (or his Holo-Me) in each of the [eight fundamental mouth shapes](https://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23581) for animating dialog -- much like *South Park*'s early days for animating dialog. For this I need the ability to get those eight mouth shapes without changing the rest of my character's pose/position. Ideally this would be possible in multiple body poses and/or locations so I can easily set the narration cuts in dynamic contexts, but even a single set of screenshots that I could rotoscope would be okay.

How can I get screenshots of these eight mouth positions from my Elite Dangerous: Odyssey character?